# SurveyMonkey - Create Webhook with AWS API Gateway as Subscription Url

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webhooks, surveymonkey

I am trying to Integrate SurveyMonkey with my backend.

This is the flow:

(1) We create a webhook(https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks) using POST method from PHP, with Subscription url as an AWS API Gateway.

(2) When user completes a survey, SurveyMonkey invokes the subscription Url (API Gateway), which in turn calls a Lambda function to update the database.

The problem is when i try to give a API Gateway url as the subscription Url, SurveyMonkey returns a Bad Request response. If i use a general .php page, the webhook is getting created successfully.

In the conversation with SurveyMonkey Support Team, they say, the API Gateway should return a 200 response for HEAD request. I am not sure how to set this up in AWS.

Can anyone who has implemented / integrated, API Gateway with SurveyMonkey please guide me on how to solve this issue?

Here is the conversation with SurveyMonkey Support Team:

> Thanks for getting back in touch.  I just spoke with my colleagues on
>   the development team and they noted that there shouldn't be an issue
>   in using a lamda function for your subscription_URL.   As long as it
>   accepts HEAD and POST requests and returns a 200.  I hope this helps
>   you out; of course, please let me know if I can assist further.
>
> Thanks for getting back in touch.  I wanted to confirm that the lambda
>   function needs to return a 200 to a HEAD request in order for us to
>   enable the webhook properly.  This isn't done after the webhook is
>   cerated, but as the webhook is created.  It still seems like the
>   lambda function isn't responding, or responding correctly, as it is
>   created, so it will continue to fail.  I hope this helps clarify;
>   please let me know if I can assist further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or another, you need to get the API Gateway to respond to `HEAD` requests. There are a lot of ways to do this. You could add a `HEAD` method to the resource of your URL. You can do that in the API Gateway console under the resource section when you're editing you api. You can send the HEAD requests to a lambda function and have that function return a `200` status code for appropriate `HEAD` requests. You can set up a mock return in the api integration request, but you'll need to set up the correct integration details. You can also just set `ANY` lambda proxy integration and deal with everything on the lambda side.

Once you have something setup you should be able to test with curl:

```
curl -I http://yourUrl.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you.. That solved the issue.. I just used the API Gateway console in AWS to create a HEAD method and by default it returned 200.